# Is there an algorithms that can list all file in the folder (for C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm working for a C# web application that can show all necessary files in one folder. For example, you have a folder named "Maps" that stores all information about New York City. I will describe this folder here: The bolded word is folders.

**Folder Maps:**

->**NewYorkCity**

->>satellite.png

->>coordinates.txt

->>bridges.png

->>**Road1**

->>>satellite1.png

->>>roads.txt

->>>houses.png

As you can see, inside folder Maps we have folder NewYorkCity, and inside of this, we have folder Road1. Now I want to collect all files that have "*.png" type. It means I want to collect all images inside the root folder. The problem here is the algorithm to collect the file. I have thought to use "for loops" but I don't know the number of subfolders so I assumed it was impossible.

Here is the code to list the file with specified type that I have used but it works for files that in one folder and doesn't have any subfolders.

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(zipPath); //Assuming Test is your Folder 
FileInfo[] Files = dInfo.GetFiles("*.png"); //Getting Text files 
string str = ""; 
foreach (FileInfo file in Files) 
{ 
    str = str + ", " + file.Name; 
}
```

I hope you understand my question. Thank you.

Comment: In order to understand recursion, one must first understand recursion. 

Directory.GetFiles("C:\\path", "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Comment: DirectoryInfo.GetFiles has an overload that allows you to get back the files with the specified extension from every subfolder of the root directoryinfo. A suggestion, before posting try always to look at the documentation. You will be surprised by the many options available there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by [reading the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=net-5.0), where you would find `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`.

Create a `DirectoryInfo` instance, and use, depending on what you want/need, any of its methods

- `EnumerateDirectories()`
- `EnumerateFiles()`
- `EnumerateFileSystemInfos()`

Like so:

```cs
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\Maps");

foreach (var fsi in di.EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*", SearchOptions.AllDirectories)
{
  // Do something useful with fsi here
}
```